# operator "delete[]": how to detect? Behavior if misuse with "delete"?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I'm with Visual Studio 2008 and compiled following code just fine.

Code1:

```
int* pI = new int[3];
delete pI;
```

Code2:

```
int* pJ = new int[3];
delete[] pJ;
```

Obviously, Code1 is wrong, because pI is allocated with "operator new[]".

Then comes the question:

1. The compiler could not pick this error (so bad), is it only the behavior of VS2008? How about later version of Visual Studio, g++, clang?

If I use "Code1" in the project,

2. Will it corrupt the heap (what kind of corrupt)?
3. Undefined behavior or Defined behavior?

Comment: It's 3. Undefined Behavior.

Comment: The compiler is not going to check every place the pointer is used to see if you are using it correctly.  If you want safe pointers then upgrade to a modern compiler and use smart pointers.

Comment: Dynamic memory debuggers like ASAN and Valgrind can find such mistakes with ease.

Comment: Static analysis tools such as clang static analyzer or cppcheck will also pick this up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: don't do this. Just don't. There's essentially *never* a good reason to use the array form of `new` (for the naysayers: no, not even when you're writing a collection class). I haven't used on in real code for over 20 years (and shouldn't have before that, but didn't realize it at the time). Usually, you should use `std::vector` instead.

Then the short answer: I don't know of a compiler that will diagnose this (at least dependably). When/if you do it, you get undefined behavior, which basically means you've broken your side of the contract with the compiler, which removes all obligations on its part.

As for what's likely to happen in practice: this seems to vary with the compiler. In some cases, your memory block will be freed without running the destructors of the objects it contains (irrelevant in your case, since `int`'s dtor is basically a nop). In other cases, the code will crash and burn. For example, consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

struct foo {
    ~foo() { std::cout << "~foo()\n"; }
};

int main() {
    foo *g = new foo[5];   
    delete g;
}
```

With VS 2015 or g++ 5.3, this crashes and burns (i.e., pops up a dialog telling you that the program has stopped working).

With some older compilers, the destructor will only run once instead of the 5 times necessary to destroy the objects that were created.

Answer (score 1):

Some compilers with static analysis tools can detect *static* incidents like the one in your code, which can never function properly. But they cannot detect all of these bugs in all cases. Particularly dynamic cases.

> Will it corrupt the heap (what kind of corrupt)?

That's not defined, since the *behavior* of deleting arrays incorrectly is not defined. It may work just fine. It may trash memory. It may corrupt the heap. It may crash your program.

That's what "undefined behavior" means.